# Rendering millions of transaction data in chart using rechart

Tags: reactjs, software-design, recharts

As I work on my React application, I'm faced with the challenge of handling millions of data points retrieved from Amazon S3 buckets, specifically Ethereum transaction data for analytics purposes. In order to visualize this data effectively, I aim to create charts. However, given the enormous volume of data, I'm unsure of the best approach to handle it. Should I manage the chart generation in the backend or explore alternative solutions?

There are some reference website which are doing the same thing which I want to do like etherscan.io. They are able to render the chart very smoothly. Does anyone has any experience with this.